# How to avoid DDoS Attack

Tags: web-browser, webserver, ddos

I buy my train ticket from our railway local web site. When ticket open for sale on web site then web site original traffic remain 50 (Just an example). Our railway web site is attacked by DDoS for this reason ticket opening time traffic show (50x50=2500). That’s why I cannot buy my ticket from our railway website. There is any way avoid DDoS attack and easily buy my ticket. My Internet Speed is 1mbps and I also try to use high quality VPN but result 0. Any kinds of help are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is there a real security problem here, or is this homework?

Comment: Our railway use paid Ddos for high traffic that's why General People cannot buy his/her ticket.

Comment: ... That's a contender for the stupidest thing I'll hear all day and it's barely even morning yet.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question in a generic way, as well as the question was asked.

If is the railway local web site that is being attacked and not you, you can not do anything to avoid this.

No matter the speed of your internet or if you are using a VPN.

To be clear, I am not considering a lot of factors here, because the question does not permits me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Someone tell me that "Best way to prevent attacks are by using your firewall on your router or computer. If you know the ports your computer is using only allow those incoming and outgoing. use netstat for the list". But I don't understand his comment. Can you help me please

Comment: @user2365514 You will not prevent the railway DDoS configuring your firewall. Are you aware?